# Usage of [path] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, disambiguation

Is there anything I can do to tidy (somewhat) ambiguous tag [path](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path)?

I noticed the tag [path](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path) has been used for two areas. One is the path to files in a computer system. Another is related to network or `distance-along-a-path` (like foot path).

Making a visual count, users used this tag for:

- File system and coding: 25
- Along a path, distance between points, shortest path: 10
- Others (related to DEM, 3D): ~4 ?

Since there is no [relative-path](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relative-path) or [absolute-path](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/absolute-path) tags, I understand the tag [path](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path) was chosen when a software user came across file path trouble (if it was not a generic IT issue).

About the `distance-along-a-path` questions, I thought of a [cost-path](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cost-path) tag. However, [cost-path](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cost-path) tag seems to have been used more specifically for cost analysis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are right that we need to disambiguate the [path](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path) tag.

I propose that a [file-path](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-path) tag be created by renaming (via a merge, using a moderator tool) the [pathname](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathname) tag.

I would not create tags for [relative-path](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relative-path) and [absolute-path](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/absolute-path) because I see these being synonyms of the [file-path](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-path) tag (at the somewhat level of granularity we use for when new tags are warranted).

Any questions about file paths which are currently tagged with the ambiguous [path](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/path) would be retagged to [file-path](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-path).

Comment: I like the [tag:file-path]. It seems (to me) currently posted four questions with [tag:pathname] tag will be good with [tag:file-path] tag. Only, I am not sure how to merge them, being not familiar with moderator tool(s)...

Comment: Ouch. I cannot accept both answers... Sorry if you see something strange happened at your end...just clicked here and there.

Comment: I probably would not accept either answer yet, to encourage others to provide answers as input.  The merge tool that I mentioned is something that only we seven moderators can do.  I usually like to see about 5 votes before using it.  Whether or not you as the asker clicks Accept on either answer won't influence much whether it is implemented because it is the community's voting that indicates whether community consensus appears to have been reached.

Comment: I understand. Let me tick it off and wait for comments/upvotes.

Comment: Thank you everyone! Five upvotes (100%) in last 24 hrs seems quite encouraging. PolyGeo, can I leave next action(s) in your hands (and moderators)?  If there is anything I can (should) do, please let me know.

Comment: @Kazuhito I've implemented the [tag:file-path] tag and put a minimalist tag wiki excerpt on it.

Comment: Great. Thanks PolyGeo! I will start working on [tag:path] posts.

Comment: I think my work on [tag:file-path] has finished, including `relative path`, and `absolute path` issues. Thanks again moderators, especially PolyGeo!